# Image loading in android studio

Tags: android, image

I am not able to load the image. I tried the following

1. put the image in the drawable folder
2. then use the Image View tag
3. then able to load the picture for the app's icon, but not able to if I try to use picture inside my application.

what should I do to use a picture inside the created application

Comment: you want to use the image in one of your layouts?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an image from drawables you shold reference it from your layout via ImageView control:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/this-is-your-image-view-id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:src="@drawable/this-is-your-drawable-name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem,fixed by using .png image,not other format .